# How to handle connection timeout while binding data to SSRSreport in C#?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

```
 private void BindReport()
    {
        try
        {
            string empID = this.txtEmpID.EmployeeID != null ? objFunctions.GetLast(this.txtEmpID.EmployeeID) : this.txtEmpID.EmployeeID;
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("EmployeePayrollReportDataSet1");
            this.rpViewer.Reset();
            using (EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataSetTableAdapters.EVS_HR_SP_EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportTableAdapter adap = new EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataSetTableAdapters.EVS_HR_SP_EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportTableAdapter())
            {
                using (EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataSet.EVS_HR_SP_EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataTable tblReport = new EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataSet.EVS_HR_SP_EmployeeAssignPayCodeReportDataTable())
                {
                    adap.Fill(tblReport, ddlCompany.SelectedValue, empID,ddlDepartment.SelectedValue);
                    rds.Value = tblReport;
                    rpViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    rpViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"SsrsReports\EmployeePayrollReport.rdlc";
                    rpViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("CompanyID", ddlCompany.SelectedValue);
                    rpViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
                    rpViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                }
            }
        }
```

Above code is working fine with less data. But when I tried to bind huge data from stored procedure then it returned an error " timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"
I know it can be handle with connection.Timeout = 0 as per my research. But I found no place to paste this "connection.timeout = 0". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `adap.Fill(tblReport, ddlCompany.SelectedValue, empID,ddlDepartment.SelectedValue)`, Do you have code accessible for Fill()?

Comment: Yes, It is adapter.Fill() function which is adapter's method.

Comment: The adapter requires a command object, that command object has `CommandTimeout` property.

Comment: It has. But it is showing that it is read only.